# Which PDE book covers these topics best?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I have an exam in January and I want to prepare ODE and PDE section first as they carry good weightage. For ODE I have S.L. Ross' book, which I like and have always referred to. But I haven't done PDE yet and I have to prepare it now. My syllabus consists of these topics-

- Linear and quasilinear first order partial differential equations
- method of characteristics; second order linear equations in two variables and their classification
- Cauchy, Dirichlet and Neumann problems; solutions of Laplace
- wave in two dimensional Cartesian coordinates
- Interior and exterior Dirichlet problems in polar coordinates
- Separation of variables method for solving wave and diffusion equations in one space variable
- Fourier series and Fourier transform and Laplace transform methods of solutions for the above equations.

My main and only focus is these topics with as many problems I can try on them. Can someone recommend a good book/s which covers all these topics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reference book I normally use for the basics on PDEs is [*Partial Differential Equations*](https://books.google.es/books?id=5Pv4LVB_m8AC), by Lawrence C. Evans. I think it covers most (maybe all) the topics you mention.